# Facebook server side authentication with partial permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using server side authentication for Facebook detailed on this page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step5

I'm asking for extended permissions like user_birthday and if the user accepts, I get the code

```
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI?
state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
&code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK
```

But if let's say the user declined to provide birthday, I still want to proceed when I get this url

```
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI?
error_reason=user_denied
&error=access_denied
&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
&state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
```

Does anyone know how to get the code under that scenario or do I have to ask the user to signin again but this time not asking for additional permissions?

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to get the code under that scenario or do I have to ask the user to signin again but this time not asking for additional permissions?

There are two scenarios here:

- You are asking the user to connect to your app for the first time. At this point, they can not decline giving you `user_birthday` permission solely (since it’s a basic and not an extended permission) – they either connect to your app, or they don’t.
- The user has connected to your app before, and now you are asking for `user_birthday` permission. If the user declines that, that will lead to the `error_reason=user_denied` – and then you will not get a `code` parameter.

In the 2nd scenario, when using the server-side flow, asking the user again (maybe with a reduced set of permissions) is the only way to go – unless you have already gotten an access token before. That will not get invalidated – but it will obviously only contain permissions already given before.

(If the user connected to your app before, you can just call the Auth dialog with no scope parameter at all – in that case Facebook will redirect straight back to your app with a code parameter. Or you could get the token beforehand client-side, for example by calling FB.getLoginStatus.)

Comment: The user can restrict user birthday in their profile. In which case even if the user clicks allow the server will still get a user_denied.